# Visualizing Raster in R?

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff

I have a dataset which I believe is generated for ArcGIS .It includes a `.tif`, `.tfw`, `.tif.aux`, `.tif.ovr` and a `.tif.vat.dbf` files.

I want to view this in R like other users view it with ArcGIS.

Is there a way?

I searched online, but I couldn't find a systematic answer. Some one says using raster but didn't give any code, and some one says there is a tool package, but no any further detail.

Comment: Would this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803503/reading-a-tif-file-in-r?

Comment: I will read through, Thank you for the link~!

Answer (score 7):

The link above from @VGu will get you started, or you can follow this [tutorial](http://neondataskills.org/R/Raster-Data-In-R/).  One thing to note, the raster library in r deals solely with single-band rasters.  For RGB and multi-band tiff files, you’ll want to use brick.  Also, if you want to do much more than viewing and simple analysis, rgdal is a good library for simple to advanced analytics.

For simple display, this will work:

```
library(raster)

grey <- raster(“pathto/singleband.tif”)
rgb <- brick(“pathto/rgb.tif”)

plot(grey)
plotRGB(rgb)
```

Comment: You can't use single backslashes like that - R treats them as control characters (`message("This\nnewline")`) - double them up or use forward slashes for paths.

Comment: Thank you! I can raster the file and plot and view it!  however, there are other four files(.tfw,.tif.ovr) also contains some info, how can I also included them in?

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman, this is updated.  As for the support files, tfw isn’t necessary because the CRS information and header information is embedded in the tiff.  I’m not sure about whether r considers the overviews, but if you use the writeRaster() function, you have the option of creating these files for use in other software.

Comment: Your comment regarding single band rasters is erroneous, referring to read functions and not the raster package. The raster::brick and raster::stack functions are for reading multi band data and raster::raster is for single band. The raster::plotRGB is for plotting RGB color composites and need the bands specified to assign to the correct color guns. Additionally, rgdal is for reading data, not analysis which is carried out by packages such as sp and spdep.

Comment: @Jeffrey Evans - good points all around.  I incorrectly stated raster and brick modules, not functions within the raster library.  But plotRGB() works with just an rgb input, defaulting to bands 3,2,1 as parameters when left blank.

Answer (score 3):

The files you've been given include the image file itself - `.tif` - as well as:

- `tfw` - the ['world' file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) (text), indicating for the image file the pixel size, coordinate of upper-left pixel and rotation values (allowing the image to be correctly placed on a coordinate plane);
- `tif.ovr` - an overlay file with reduced-resolution versions of the original tif, allowing rapid display of the image at different zoom levels;
- `.tif.vat.dbf` - most likely a table for the legend values;
- `.tif.aux` - [auxiliary data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/auxiliary-files.htm) (metadata, etc).

In R, `plot()` is always a good place to start:

```
library(raster)
fn <- "srtm_44_13/srtm_44_13.tif"
r1 <- raster(fn)
plot(r1)
```

[image]

With specific colours:

```
plot(r1, breaks = c(0, 1000, 4000, 6000), col = terrain.colors(4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed file explanation! I can't vote up right now~ but really appreciate!

Comment: You should be able to vote up with >15 rep and can definitely click the check mark to 'accept' an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the game, but the successor to the `raster` package has been released and changes things slightly, but is *much much* more efficient in everything it does.

Here is some code for a simple plot:

```
library(terra)
xx <- rast("pathto/singleband.tif")
plot(xx)
```

The package is currently in it's early days, so most external plotting functions haven't incorporated it just yet. I will update this when they do, if someone gives me a nudge.